# Как открыть ссылку в стандартном браузере Андроид

Tags: android, java, webview

Всем доброе утро. Столкнулся с проблемой перехода по ссылке на андроид!

Использую два варианта:
Первый просто отправляю ссылку через интент action_view:

```
        buy_k = "<a href=http://example.com/AutoFillCart.aspx?ID=" + consult_code +"&countryCode=RU&Goods=" +
                sortirovka[36].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[35].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[34].key + "/1@"+ sortirovka[33].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[32].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[31].key + "/1@" + sortirovka[30].key + "/1@" + 
                sortirovka[29].key + "/1";


(findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri address = Uri.parse(buy_k);
            Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
            startActivity(openlink);

        }
      });
Второй вариант хочу реализовать выбор приложения:
(findViewById(R.id.button3)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Uri address = Uri.parse(buy_k);
    Intent openlink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, address);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(openlink, "Browser"));

}
```

});

В первом случае выкидывает из приложения, во втором говорит что отсутствует приложение для выполнения этих целей. Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: а зачем в начале урла добавлять `<a href=`? этого точно не нужно. Нужен просто урл, который будет начинаться с `http://` или `https://`.

@AlexWindHope это все бады.

Comment: Точно точно! Просто до этого я отображал ссылки в Webview, а теперь забыл убрать href. Спасибо большое! А что значит это все бады? Звучит смешно, но не понимаю причины?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, Ваше приложение будет продвигать продукт, который улучшает все, что только можно. В том числе, якобы, и здоровье. Но по факту это обычный [БАД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%90%D0%94). Это ни чуть не лучше спама.

Comment: Может быть оно и так, но моя задача это реалищация, просто пипец как замудренной системы подбора, что я сам уже начинаю путаться в простом! Я сам столкнулся с БАДами только когда начал работу над этим приложением! БАД это просто пресованная трава или фрукты!)

Comment: всегда есть возможность отказаться. А на месте модераторов я бы потер Ваши ссылки  - а то они являются скрытой рекламой. А то и забанил бы. Честно.

Система подбора "замудренная" только по одной причине - что бы запутать.

Comment: Но здесь ведь нет ни одной рабочей ссылки! А запутать, они меня запутали. Больше сотни вопросо, описаний каждого продута, более двух сотен сертификатов и подобной ерунды в одно приложении, короче дурдом!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ в комментариях. Значит вопрос надо закрывать!

Comment: Почитайте хотя бы гайды по оформлению джава кода, там же основное все просто, а то смотреть трудно на такой код. Не воспринимайте как упрек, просто просьба, и вам самому потом будет удобнее воспринимать чужой (любой) код как привыкните

Answer (score 1):

В начале URL лишние символы `<a href=`.
Здесь не нужно использовать тег.